# I want to update map with the user's location co-ordinates. The map is first rendered but not getting updated

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update the map coordinates with the user's location. Right now what is happening the ng-maps is getting loaded with defined constants. Geolocation service gets the user coordinates but map is not getting updated.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app='App'>
    <head>
      <style type='text/css'>
       body, html { height: 50%; margin: 0;}
       .google-map { height: 50%; }
      </style>
      <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
      <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js'></script>
      <script src='Scripts/ng-maps.js'></script>
      <script>


          angular.module('App', ['ngMaps'])

          .factory('GeolocationService', [
                '$q', '$window', '$rootScope', function ($q, $window, $rootScope){
                    return function () {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();

                        if (!$window.navigator) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                                deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation is not supported"));
                            });
                        } else {
                            $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                                    deferred.resolve(position);
                                });
                            }, function (error) {
                                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                                    deferred.reject(error);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }])


          .controller('Main',['$scope', 'GeolocationService', function ($scope, geolocation)  {

              geolocation().then(function (position) {
                  console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                  console.log(position.coords.longitude);
                      //$scope.position = position;
                  $scope.map = {
                      center: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]
                  }

                  $scope.marker = {
                      position: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude],
                      options: function () {
                          return {
                              draggable: true
                          }
                      },
                      events: {
                          click: function (e) {
                              alert(e.latLng)
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }, function (reason) {
                  $scope.message = "Could not be determined."
              });
              $scope.apply();


          }]);
      </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="Main">
      <map ng-transclude class='google-map' center="map.center" > 
        <marker position="marker.position" options="marker.options" events="marker.events"></marker>
      </map>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I am new to angular might be missing a smaal.

Comment: It should be $scope.$apply() at the end.

Comment: $scope.$apply() is there, should i move it from there.

Comment: apply() is there but not $apply()

Comment: but its not required at all. Aren't you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Yes I am getting erros  with $scope.$apply();  also